# WCF. What is the performance difference between async and sync methods on a service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous, task

lets assume that we have two operation contracts defined on wcf service, sync and async one. There are two samples:

```
public void SubscribeSingle(int userId)
{
    var clientId = this.OperationContext.GetClientId();
    var session = this.OperationContext.GetPollingDuplexSession();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientId) || session == null || userId == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.InternalSubscribeSingle(userId, clientId, session.SessionId);
}
```

and

```
public IAsyncResult BeginUnsubscribeSingle(int userId, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    var clientId = this.OperationContext.GetClientId();
    var session = this.OperationContext.GetPollingDuplexSession();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientId) || session == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var asyncResult = new VoidAsyncResult(callback, state);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            this.InternalUnsubscribeSingle(userId, clientId);
            asyncResult.SetAsCompleted(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            asyncResult.SetAsCompleted(ex, false);
        }
    });
    return asyncResult;
}


public void EndUnsubscribeSingle(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var response = result as VoidAsyncResult;
    if (response != null)
    {
        response.EndInvoke();
    }
}
```

As I understand WCF service also has a thread pool inside, so each I/O operation may be finished on another thread. As well as starting new thread using Task.Factory.StartNew

Is there any difference between sync and async server calls from performance point of view, if database access is made through EntityFramework and though blocking?

Comment: FYI Stephen Toub has an article about performance implications of asynchrony using the Task-based Asynchrony Pattern in this month's MSDN magazine. You can read it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no value to the async method here, since you're still calling a sync method that will block a thread at some point.  The async only earns something when it goes all the way down to a non-blocking operation like disk/network IO.  Just write the simple sync version and let WCF do its thing.

Answer (score 2):

This two versions are the same. But in general asynchronous version could be much more efficient than calling synchronous version asynchronously.

For example, if we're using [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) or [TcpListerner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx), than calling asynchronous version of BeginRead and BeginAcceptSocket whould be much more efficient than calling appropriate synchronous versions like Read and AcceptSocket. Thats because those asynchronous functions using underlying asyncrhonous API provided by operating system.

For example, TcpListener could use IO completion ports for interacting with another tcp client and with this approach you can easily interact with 10K of clients asyncrhnously without delays . FileSteam could use Overlapped structure for underlying asynchronous operations that would consume less resources than synchronous version.

So if your services asynchronous method could as well use some asynchronous underlying API your async version could be much more efficient than simple async version that calls sync version in different thread.